# Translating Localhost to Fully Qualified Domain Name

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, https

I'm setting up a server that will be used for automated UI tests against a web interface. I'm using Chromedriver as the browser driver, so it just takes a passed in URL from the test code.

Because of the way the automation is set up, I use a generic URL: `https:\\localhost\<blah>`.

However, this generates a certificate warning because we are using `localhost` and not the fully qualified domain name, so it doesn't match up. I'm using a self-signed certificate since these are not Internet-facing servers and are disposable machines.

My question is, on a Windows Server 2012 IIS server, how can I either tell IIS to recognize `localhost` as the same as `servername.forest.domain.com`, or translate this somewhere on the server?

If it's not possible to do this at the server layer I'll look at changing the test code to pull from a servername variable instead, but I wanted to see if this was an option first.

Comment: Have you tried editing the IIS bindings for the site so that they use 'localhost' instead of the FQDN of the site? Worth noting that the SSL cert will still generate a warning in a browser though unless it is actually named 'localhost' and installed in the machine under the trusted root certification authorities store.

Comment: I did try that, but I still get the warning in Chrome and the HTTPS marking has the "red slash" through it, thus leading me to believe it's not actually a secured connection.

Comment: That just means the browser doesn't trust the SSL cert because it was not issued by a CA (you mentioned it was self-signed) or that the name of the site doesn't match the name on the cert ('localhost' vs FQDN).

Comment: If you really need the SSL certificiate to be trusted I would just use LetsEncrypt. It's free and the easiest way to quickly get a trusted SSL cert for public use.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense, it's still securing communication but the browser just doesn't trust it. I'll double check that the traffic looks right in Fiddler and go on with my day. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it's really more a browser issue than anything. For instance, you can set Firefox to just ignore it and it's a "out of sight, out of mind" thing. LAN use only, it's almost never really applicable (on the internet is a completely different story, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a host entry for the Server IP address in %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file for your fqdn.

Comment: This is I good idea, I forgot about the hosts file. I added `127.0.0.1   localhost` to the hosts file but it looks like it still doesn't resolve properly. If try to browse to `https:\\localhost\<blah>` it still shows as improperly resolving

Comment: If you ping localhost, what ip address do you get?

Comment: The FQDN and ::1. The replies come from ::1:

Comment: ::1 is the IPv6 loopback address, that is normal.